# JavaScript meaning of #text in htmlNode.childNodes[i].nodeName

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am new to JavaScript and when I was playing around with the DOM model I was getting confused when I wanted to display all `nodeName`s from the HTML `childNodes`.
There is a `nodeName` called *#text* when i have an `head` tag and when I delete the complete `head` tag there is the normal *HEAD* and *BODY* `nodeName`.
What means the *#text* `nodeName` especally when I have a `head` tag?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>          
        <p id="p1">SOME TEXT</p>    
        <button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeNode()">Click </button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeNode() {
            var htmlNode = document.documentElement;                
            var anzahl = htmlNode.childNodes.length;

            var html_text = "<p>";
            for(var i = 0;i<anzahl;i++){
                html_text += " " + htmlNode.childNodes[i].nodeName +";";
            }
            html_text += "</p>";
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = html_text;
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The output of it is (with the `head` tag):

> HEAD; #text; BODY;

The output of it is (without the `head` tag):

> HEAD; BODY;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are HTML DOM #text elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357004/what-are-html-dom-text-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespace inside elements is considered as #text, and text is considered as nodes. Remove the space between `</head>` & `<body>` tag like below:

```
<html>
 <head></head><body>         
    <p id="p1">SOME TEXT</p>    
    <button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeNode()">Click </button>
 </body>
```

This will give you the output
HEAD,BODY

Answer (score 3):

> What means the #text nodeName especally when i have a head tag.

these are the empty line breaks that you have unintentionally introduced in your markup.

Use `children` instead of `childNodes` if you don't want to include text nodes.