# What does an array with the value #text in the index 0 mean?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

What does an array with the value #text in the index 0 mean And where did it come from?
I explained my meaning below.

this is HTML code:

```
<div class="todo-container">
    <div class="todoList">
  
    </div>
  </div>
```

and this is JS code:

```
const todoList = document.querySelector(".todoList");
 
//function

function filtersTodo(e) {
const todos = [... todoList.childNodes];
console.log(todos);
}
```

And this is what it shows me as output:[img of output console.log(todos)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlkNd.jpg)

[another picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOsk3.jpg)

My question is where Array [#text] came from and why?

Comment: Well, it's a text node: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text

Comment: ok But it should not be shown to me as output

Comment: `parent.childNodes` gives you all node types.  `parent.children` gives you just element children.

Comment: ok this is helpful but in `div with class=todoList `  node with type text does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Everything in the DOM is represented by a node. Including plain text."

See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21357034/16633894